# SQL Interview: How to find most affected users based on applications migrated... in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, report

I have a table with list of Users that has two columns Username and FullName.

I have a table with list of Applications that has two columns Id and Name.

I have a table with a list of Applications that Users have, UserApplications, it has two columns, Username and ApplicationId.

The UserApplications table defines that applications a user has on their computer.

On a project where users are awaiting for applications to be upgraded, how do I get a report that shows a list of applications that would satisfy the most users. I need to generate a report of n (1 to 10) applications. e.g. if resources are available to migrate n applications, which n applications would satisfy most amount of users so the remaining applications can be done sequentially.

Also need to generate a list of applications that would satisfy the most users immediately if migrated in order.

Dialect is MS SQL

Comment: You haven't made any effort to answer this yourself, and you haven't tagged it correctly.

Comment: I wrote a java program to model this and after generating 4 app list, the 5 app list takes way too long to complete.

Comment: What tags should I be using?

Comment: [sql-server] would be a good one, possibly also including version number or [sql-azure] if your database is on azure

Comment: Thanks. It's not an azure database.

Answer (score 1):

This is a re-phrasing of the query given by Dick Appel, and I break it down for benefit of your understanding:

```
SELECT
  ApplicationId, count(*) as AppCount
FROM
  UserApplications
GROUP BY 
  ApplicationID
```

Hopefully you can easily see that this query will give a unique list of application ids, and the count of the number of users that have that app

Now we need some more detail about the application. We don't care about any user detail. We take that query above and turn it io a subquery (actually we don't have to but it's easier to see what goes on if we do)

```
SELECT ApplicationName, AppCount
FROM
(

 SELECT
   ApplicationId, count(*) as AppCount
 FROM
   UserApplications
 GROUP BY 
   ApplicationID

) appcounts
INNER JOIN
Applications
ON
  app counts.ApplicationID = Applications.ApplicationID
ORDER BY AppCount DESC
```

The subject that does the counts per ID is joined to the applications table that gives detail on each ID. It is ordered descending by the count of apps

After this point we really need to know what database is in use to limit the results to 10, as different database have different syntax. Dick used sql server syntax. Oracle or MySQL would have LIMIT 10 in the outer query, and the subquery would possibly need to be the one that was ordered

Comment: Dialect is ms sql. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could go a couple of ways here, but somthing like this (don't know which dialect you would be using ) -- basically create a subquery that just produces a list of all applications that have users and the number of users they have ('ApplicationUserCount') and order that with the outer query in descending order.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Application, UserCount 
  FROM (SELECT A.ApplicationName as Application, COUNT(*) as UserCount 
          FROM Applications A 
    INNER JOIN UserApplications UA ON (A.ApplicationId = UA.ApplicationId)
      GROUP BY A.ApplicationName ) ApplicationUserCount
ORDER BY UserCount DESC
```

Comment: So, if the top most application is migrated, that'll satisfy the most number of users?